# Run code when navigation drawer first begins to open

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I am building off of the `NavigationDrawerFragment` that can be auto-generated by Android Studio.  It comes with functionality to show a global title and global menu (for the action bar) when the drawer is opened.  It does this in an `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, using the @overriden methods `onDrawerClosed` and `onDrawerOpened`.

My question is, how can I make the context switch happen when the drawer first begins to open, rather than when it is completely open?  I noticed that the `gmail` app does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [`DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.onDrawerStateChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html#onDrawerStateChanged%28int%29) in your `ActionBarToggle` and make a call to `Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu` there. If you wanted to invalidate the menu more precisely you could compare the `newState` parameter to `DrawerLayout.STATE_IDLE`, `DrawerLayout.STATE_DRAGGING`, or `DrawerLayout.STATE_SETTLING`.

Similarly, you could also override [`DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.onDrawerSlide`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html#onDrawerSlide%28android.view.View,%20float%29).

Then use [`DrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#isDrawerVisible%28android.view.View%29) rather than [`DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#isDrawerOpen%28android.view.View%29) in `Activity.onPrepareOptionsMenu`.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    final boolean drawerVisible = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_item_id).setVisible(!drawerVisible);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  I went with the latter method.